# Running a jar in php

Tags: java, php

Can you run a java jar file in php?

Like when you press a button the jframe that you made pops-up in the website.

I've already searched for bridging php and java but I think it's about running a java jar file that returns something and not the actual jframe itself.

Comment: something like this: `exec('java -jar file.jar');`

Comment: That would have to be an applet. PHP has nothing to do with this at all, its not like PHP is running in the browser which is where you want the frame to 'popup'. You are aware that people nowadays basically block, ban and condemn all forms of Java applets and Flash right?

Comment: I'll try to see if there are any other way I can implement it without using java applets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You could run the jar file, if php is capable of executing system commands (which it probably is), just like you'd do it normally. With `java -jar myjar.jar`.

However this would run it on the server. When you're viewing a web page, you're not on the server, you're the client. You'll never see the JFrame that popped up on the server (provided that it has a graphical environment).

Comment: Basically I just tried to make the management side php and the java for commmunicating with the hardware, I wanted the admin to be able to launch the jarfile when he pressed a button. Since I'm running it in localhost it would make this possible right? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure Tomcat with Apache HTTP server AJP-proxy and ProxyPass certain URIs to Tomcat. This will enable you to execute code in any JAR-file that is known to the JVM running Tomcat and your application.